# Scala map-filtering methods

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, rdd

I'm new to Scala and Spark. I'm trying to remove duplicate rows of a text file.
Each row contains three columns (vector values), such as : -4.5,-4.2,2.7

This is my program :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

object WordCount {

 def main(args: Array[String]) {

   val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount").setMaster("local[*]")
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
   val input =  sc.textFile("/opt/spark/WC/WC_input.txt")

   val keys = input.flatMap(line => line.split("/n"))

   val singleKeys = keys.distinct

   singleKeys.foreach(println)
 }
}
```

It works, but I wanted to know if there was a way to employ the filter function. I have to use it in my program, but I don't know how to iterate among all the rows and remove the duplicates (with a loop for example).

If anybody has an idea, would be great!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think using `filter` to do that wouldn't be a very effective solution. For each element you would have to either see if this element is already present in some sort of temporary dataset or calculate how much of these elements are in processed dataset.

If you want to iterate over it and maybe do some on-the-fly edits you can apply `map` and then `reduceByKey` to group same elements. Like this

```
val singleKeys = 
    keys
    .map( element => ( element , 0 ) )
    .reduceByKey( ( element, count ) => element )
    .map( _._1 )
```

where you can do changes to the dataset in the first `map` part. `count` parameter is not used although by definition of `reduceByKey` we need a second parameter in Tuple or Map.

I think this is basically how `distinct` internally works.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate elements of RDD can be removed in this way:

```
val data = List("-4.5,-4.2,2.7", "10,20,30", "-4.5,-4.2,2.7")
val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val result = rdd.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).filter(_._2 == 1).map(_._1)
result.foreach(println)
```

Result:

```
10,20,30
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! But I wanted to keep one instance of all duplicate elements. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, if remove "filter" clause. Result will be the same as "distinct".

Comment: You're the best! Thanks (: